# docker python: committed changes in a container but new image does not run

Tags: python, docker

i have a python image called `python-example`
with container_id = `c08e4ee85879`

Inside exist a python script that prints `hello world`

## file.py

```
print "HELLO WORLD"
```

if i run my image:
`docker run python-example` the output `HELLO WORLD` will be printed on my terminal and then the container will exit.

When i try to enter the container to make a change to the script through vim, exit the container and commit the change to a new image and then try to run the new image, nothing get printed. See steps below

```
docker run -it python-example bash
vim file.py
#make some changes by adding a new print statement "HELLO WORLD 2"
exit
docker commit c08e4ee85879 python-example2

docker run python-example2 #now nothing gets printed to terminal screen
```

When i enter the new image then run python file.py, the output gets printed.

```
docker run -it python-example2 bash
python file.py
"HELLO WORLD"
"HELLO WORLD 2"
```

Why is this so? Is it not possible for an image to run when changes are commited in bash?

Comment: would you please add the output of `docker inspect python-example2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

Change your commit to:

```
docker commit --change='CMD ["python", "file.py"]' c08e4ee85879 python-example2
```

**Explanation**

When you run:

`docker run -it python-example bash`

you are changing your default command (which is `python file.py` to `bash`).

You can check with `docker ps`.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
c08e4ee85879        python-example        "bash"                   32 seconds ago      Up 30 seconds                           thirsty_hugle
```

[Check dockerfile reference - CMD for more information](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

With `--change='CMD ["python", "file.py"]'` you get the desired command back.